# CSV write data in same line

Tags: c#, csv

I am generating CSV this is my code:

```
public ActionResult MethodName()
{
   List<ModelName> m = new List<ModelName>();

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (ModelName s in m)
      {
          sb.Append(s.FName).Trim();
          sb.Append(",");
          sb.Append(s.SName).trim();
          sb.Append(","); /* I doubt you want this one */

          sb.AppendLine();
      }

  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
  return File(bytes, "text/comma-separated-values", "FileName.csv");

}
```

The data which I am getting looks something like this when I press f12 
`FName
,SName
,Address, Zipcode
,somethingElse`

What I want here is have a .csv file where first column contains FName, second column SName, Third column Address etc... yes I have not placed address in my code but its easy once I know why all these data are in different lines 
**update**
`fname
                         sname`

Comment: Check how `FName` and `SName` come from `ModelName`. It's possible to be stored with a new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
foreach (ModelName s in m)
  {
      sb.Append(s.FName.ToString().Replace("\n",""));
      sb.Append(",");
      sb.Append(s.SName.ToString().Replace("\n",""));
      sb.Append(","); /* I doubt you want this one */

      sb.AppendLine();
  }
```

Comment: I get an error when I type this line `   sb.Append(s.FName.Replace("\n",""));` it says `Non-invocable member ModelName.FName cannot be used like a method`?

Comment: @User911: you need to invoke ToString before applying Replace method,check my edited answer

Comment: your correct I fixed it. but your solution provides same result I get fname in one column and sname in second column below first - see my question

Comment: @User911: can you debug and see what exactly `s.SName` and `s.FName` contains?

Comment: when i press f12 fname is e.g. Jack and sname is Mack. I think its because in second line we're saying `sb.Append(s.SName..` we're appending after first name but i want sname to be in same line (next cell) not in next line

Comment: @User911: can you move the `writer.Flush();` statement out of the loop.

Comment: I found out - I was missing Trim() at the end so ` sb.Append(s.FName.ToString().Replace("\n","").Trim());` just a final question how would I place headings on this?

Comment: @User911: great :) , i don't have any idea, please raise another post, all the best.

Comment: I would suggest using Environment.Newline instead of "\n", as this will also match the newline characters on Windows machines.